# Eclipse & Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, eclipse

I have installed Eclipse along with the Web Developer tools -- I am trying to do Javascripting in Eclipse but wanted to know if there are specific other plug-ins/kits I need in order to do so. Currently I build using:

```
File -> New -> Web -> Dynamic Web Project ||
File -> New -> HTML File ||
File -> New -> JSP File
```

To be able to run JavaScript as the materials I am learning/working off of. However I am unable to have any JavaScript event handling capabilities in the Eclipse environment.

As an example I have the following HTML file:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<script src="keyboardTest.js"></script>
<title>pageTest</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

---------------------
```

And keyboardTest.js file:

```
---------------------


alert("inside keyboardTest.js");

var main = function(){

$(document).keypress(function(event){
    alert("HERE");
     if(event.which === 65){
        /** A  **/
        alert("A");
    }
    else if(event.which == 69){
         /** E  **/
        alert("E");
    }
     else if(event.which===70){
        /** F  **/
        alert("F");
    }
    else if(event.which===32){
        /** SPACE_BAR **/
        alert("space_bar");
    }
});
}


$(document).ready(main)`
```

---

But the HTML doesn't trigger the Javascript within the inner function main--it does however send the very first ALERT(). Concurrently when I move the files to a directory on my computer the javascript ALERT works, but not the event readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using jQuery syntax here: `$(document)`
But you haven't included the jQuery framework to you html file. Add jQuery and it should work:

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! I've been doing online courses and they left out that bit about including the jQuery library